# Print не работает после pip install python-docx

Tags: print, docx, python-docx

Windows 8.1 Professional x64. Python 3.10.5
В програмку загружается word документ в котором есть некий текст и задача програмки провести работу с точками, которые есть в тексте.

```
import docx
def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)


a = getText(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.docx')
print(a) # вывел текст - Американский предприниматель Илон Маск раскритиковал YouTube. Распространение мошеннической рекламы и политику в отношении мата.

n = a.split(".")
print(n) # вывел массив - ['Американский предприниматель Илон Маск раскритиковал YouTube', Распространение мошеннической рекламы и политику в отношении мата']
if a.endswith("."):
    my_list = a.split(".")[:-1]
    print(my_list) # ничего не вывел
```

Выходит сообщение что "Process finished with exit code 0"(Типа код выполнен). Но почему print(my_list) не выводит сообщение? Установлен только python-docx (через pip install python-docx). Проблема кроется в python-docx - не знаю что с ним делать, перерыл всё что мог. HELP!

Comment: добавьте побольше отладочной информации (print в разных местах, с выводом что получили, например, print(a)). вероятно последний if не сработал.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что текст кончается точкой после которой идёт перевод строки. И ваш код печатает этот самый перевод строки, который на экране просто не видно никак.

Comment: @Алексей Обухов расставил print'ы, да последний if нивкакую не хочет выводить инфу из print(my_list)

Comment: значит `if a.endswith("."):` условие `False`. Попробуйте без него и если сработает, по подберите более подходящее условие

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос **точный** вывод ваших команд `print`. Ну не соответствует то, что вы в комментариях добавили, тому, что должно напечататься с таким текстом. Вы где-то посчитали какую-то информацию не нужной и сократили. А зря. Прямо вот отдельным блоком кода добавьте **весь** вывод вашей программы. Буквальный, без искажений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос. Нужно было вместо if a.endswith(".") написать if a.find("."):

Comment: Тогда уж `if "." in a:`